# Fixing 404 after migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, nopcommerce

I've migrated a site from Nopcommerce to WordPress.

I find that I've generated from 700 to 4000 404 errors.

What can I do to massively tell Google to consider this?

Should I redirect all the URLs one by one using redirection plugin? I need to get back on track with my SEO.

Comment: did you re-indexed in webmaster tools?

Comment: Is there a common pattern between the old 404s and the new URL that replaces it? Consider using `mod_rewrite` to fix this. You can usually set it up in an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I re-indexed the site in webmastertools. The site url structure changed completely. The domain is the same. My question is: for old url (that only come from my site - url's that are linked only from my page), if i remove or mark the 404 as solved, it  won't come again, right? Why should I in this case redirect? Wouldn't reindexing be enough for google? Or i still need to redirect all urls that are only internally linked?

Answer (score 0):

this means you have completely new URLs for your website, and so all old URL's are down?

If your URLs have a new version on your WordPress:

- I think that yes, you should do manual 301 redirections from old URLs to their new version.

If your URLs have no new version on your WordPress:

- you could temporarily redirect all 404 URLs to your Wordpress homepage. Or the entire domain if you changed the domain name.

Comment: also - if there are a lot of common structures, from the old to new, like categories or similar - you can create a regex, that will forward to the new post in in the new path - the more similarities and common rules you can make, the easier for you and the system.

Comment: Exactly, almost all of the urls are down. I reindexed the entire site. The domain is the same. Do you think it's appropriate to redirect the entire domain? Or is it better to manually fix the 404's with proper url or regex?